# manually configure webserver for asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-web-developer

i m using visual web developer 2010 and on selecting new website option via HTTP i am getting this error...please help

Comment: Question is really poorly asked, please next time provide more detail in the body question, even if the title itself contains some.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make sure ASP.NET 4.0 is registered with IIS. If it isn't you could register it with the following command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i
```

and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

`C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis`

(Choose whatever framework to register with IIS me selecting Framework 4)

Double-click or right click & choose run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, The way I went about solving it was not by registering the `.NET` version. the issue comes down the the `.net` version on the `MySQL` connector that you are using, as per my example:

Project using `.NET 4.0`, however I was adding a reference to `MySQL` DLL connectors under the 4.5.

Under the path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.9.8\Assemblies
```

There should be a variety of assemblies where you add the reference to, make sure it matches the `.NET` that the project is using.

Hope this helps.